# unable to complie and install perl module: Audio::Scan

Tags: perl, gcc, visual-c++, compiler-errors, nmake

i am using "perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int" on windows 7 enterprise(SP1). 
I am trying to compile and install a perl module Audio::Scan (.71 version). I downloaded the module from cpan.org, extracted it locally in my machine. It contains readme.win32 text file which states the following:

### zlib

The included zlib.lib should just work, if not: Download zlib from http://www.zlib.net/zlib123.zip. 
Build from projects/visualc6/zlib.dsw. 
Build Win32_LIB_Release Copy zlib.lib into the Audio::Scan win32 directory.

### Audio::Scan

Install ActivePerl 5.8.8 or 5.10.0. Open command prompt. Run the vcvars file, for example C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\vcvarsall.bat 
perl Makefile.PL 
nmake

### nmake test

END 
I followed all the steps till nmake. The step before nmake i executed like this "perl Makefile.PL make=nmake" as it was generating it dmake style by default. This step goes well. 
But in nmake step, i get a lot of warnings followed by the following error:

win32/zlib.lib(./Win32_LIB_Release/crc32.obj):(.text$mn+0x22): undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4' 
win32/zlib.lib(./Win32_LIB_Release/crc32.obj):(.text$mn+0x1be): undefined reference to`@__security_check_cookie@4'

c:/perl/site/lib/auto/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: win32/zlib.lib(./Win32_LIB_Release/crc32.obj): bad reloc address 0x1be in section `.text$mn'

c:/perl/site/lib/auto/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Perl\site\bin\g++.EXE' : return code '0x1' 
Stop.

I read this thread http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=496624 checked the compiler used to compile perl as follows: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC>perl -V:cc.. 
it returned

cc='gcc';

I am stuck at this point. Any help would be highly appreciated. Sorry for typos if any.

Comment: Which distro is your 5.18.2? Strawberry? Activestate? Compiled by yourself from source? It is required that you use the same compiler that was used to compile Perl in order to compile extensions such as the XS code in Audio-Scan. You should not follow the instructions from README.win32 literally, installing an additional Perl distro from ten years when you already have one is not going to help you.

Comment: @daxim Actually, it is not that bad. With my VS2013 built `perl`, all I had to do was to unconditionally `include` `zlib.h` in `id3.h`, add `zlib.lib` to `@LIBS` in `Makefile.PL`. I have my own `zlib` build, and its `include` and `lib` directories were in my `%INCLUDE%` and `%LIB%`. After those changes all tests pass.

Comment: @vamank It seems to me you should download and extract a fresh copy of the distro, then do `perl Makefile.PL` and then `make test`, `make install` given that you have a `perl` built using a `gcc` based toolchain and you are trying to use Visual Studio's `nmake`.

Comment: @daxim its activestate perl

Comment: got a working copy audio scan library here: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1195192

Comment: @daxim yes it is activestate perl